# database struct diagram

Tags: database, database-design

What are good references for database design diagrams? Examples would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what at what grade level of DB design you were looking for but here are a couple of possibilities.

For basic DB design in general, one of my favorites is "Case*Method Entity Relationship Modeling" by Richard Barker.  It is an old book (1990) but is very clear and well written with many good examples.

For more advanced business modeling "Analysis Patterns, Reusable Object Models" by Martin Fowler is good.  It has chapters on Accountability, Planning, Contracts as well as many others.